# Changing size of leaflet.wms plugin popup in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo, leaflet-plugins

I've created a webmap viewer with `Leaflet` and used the plugin `leaflet.wms` to call the WMS GetFeatureInfo service to query a map layer and return information about the underlying features. My code is as follows

```
var source = L.WMS.source("http://xxxx/geoserver/wms",
                    {
                        "format": "image/png",
                        "transparent": "true",
                        "attribution": "© Instituto Geográfico Nacional de España",
                        "info_format": "text/html",         
                    }        
                );
var lyrAtlas = source.getLayer("atlas:lista_reprod_iii");
```

It works fine, but the information to be returned is quite long and the displayed popup is too narrow, so the result is unmanageable. I want to set the width of the popup to something wider, but I haven't found any hint to obtain it. Is it possible to do so?

**Edit**

This is the only chunk of code of the plugin js file where the popup appears:

```
'showFeatureInfo': function(latlng, info) {
    // Hook to handle displaying parsed AJAX response to the user
    if (!this._map) {
        return;
    }
    this._map.openPopup(info, latlng);
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to do is to define your own `showFeatureInfo` option/method where you can set width of the popup like @Ziggy suggested. To do this you can use `include` method to modify `L.WMS.Source` class (see https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html).

Code for modifying `L.WMS.Source` class could look something like this:

```
L.WMS.Source = L.WMS.Source.include({
  'showFeatureInfo': function(latlng, info) {
    L.popup({minWidth: 600})
      .setLatLng(latlng)
      .setContent(info)
      .openOn(map);
  }
});
```

Comment: It depends on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Its in the leaflet popup [properties](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup)

```
var popup =  L.popup({
  maxWidth: 375
})
```

Comment: I'm unable to make this code to work. I'm editing the question adding code from the plugin.